# Save State of Random Number Generator C#

Tags: c#, random, pseudocode

This is under the assumption that if I make a new random number generator and feed it a seed it will always repeat the same pattern at run time for example lets say my random number generator outputs the following, one digit at a time:

```
123456789
```

Is there a way to save the state of the random number generator? So that I could run the program and have it return:

```
12345
```

Then save the state; end the program; fire it back up and it will then return:

```
6789
```

Apologizes if Stack Overflow isn't the place for this vague concept.

Comment: If the pattern is predicable then it isn't really random.

Comment: I'm curious why? Maybe understanding the "why" will help provide a better solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512210/how-to-save-the-state-of-a-random-generator-in-c

Comment: Thanks Demur, it works.