# How to get the Nth instance of a Random.Next()?

Tags: c#, random

I was hoping there's a built in method in Random for this, but there isn't? So I came up with this function to return the nth instance of a random seed:

```
public class Program {
static int seed = 123; // This could be anything

static int NextN(int n, int range) // Get the nth instance of seed
{
    Random rand = new Random(seed);
    List<int> pool = new List<int>();
    while( pool.Count< n+1 ){ pool.Add(rand.Next(range)); }
    return pool[n];
}
public static void Main() 
{
    Console.WriteLine(NextN(8,100)); // Return 19 as the 8th value of seed 123 at 100 range.
}}
```

As you can see, the NextN() function generate the sequence of random numbers first, then return the value of the nth instance. This will perform badly once you're trying to reach a very high instance (like in the millions). Since random always return the same value each time you restart an app, I need to keep track how many times the random seed is accessed between session. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Why do you specify the seed? Leave it empty and it uses time as seed which is different each time

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512210/how-to-save-the-state-of-a-random-generator-in-c

Comment: Are you looking for a way to create truly random numbers? What's your ultimate goal?

Comment: I think the goal is to have a deterministic set of random numbers even after restarting the app. It's often used for procedurally generated content, or in videogames to prevent players from cheating the RNG by saving/reloading until they get the result they want

Comment: Only the seed is randomed at first, then it's locked between session. Then I need a fixed (random) seqeunce from the seed. *Just like Kevin Gosse said, to prevent cheating.

Comment: Closing as dupe then, this is the exact same need as the question I linked.

Comment: Wasn't the link is about saving the Random state? I'm trying to use this as a standalone.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the nuance, but I gotta run so I'm reopening it and leaving this to whoever's around :)

Comment: Will the range change between sessions? If not, why is it passed as a parameter?

Comment: it's just an example, but I prefer it to be dynamic later.

Comment: In .Net Framework you could just serialize your Random instance between sessions. Did you try that? Or are you targetting core?

Comment: Saving random's state is exactly how games would do it. I don't see reason why you would not do it like that.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this in a single clean method. If it's not possible without saving the random state, guess it'll have to do.

Comment: Why are you storing "n-1" values that you ignore anyway? Just overwrite a single int value in the loop and use its latest value.